# Coping One server files to another server

Tags: data

There is a SharePoint server at another branch of our company and it has data. We need to move that data to a different file server in a usable format.

How can this be done.

I have been googling a lot for this unfortunately not getting options.

Comment: what type of data you want to move other server and in which application you want to use it?

Answer (score 0):

From the server you want to copy from, open Explorer and type

```
\\NewServer\c$\
```

And sign in with the credentials needed on the new server.